# What does the message "start worker process" mean when I run a Docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Whenever I execute `docker-compose` for a particular app of mine, I see printed a flurry of "start worker process" messages:

```
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 77
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 78
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 79
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 80
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 81
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 82
2022/03/31 19:24:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 83
```

I'm guessing this message is a very generic one and that's why I can't find any discussions about it. Nevertheless I'm interested to know:

- what process/software/daemon/package is responsible for printing the message
- what types of events triggers the message

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      network: host
      context: cfg/nginx/.
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/var/www/web_reflectivity/static
      - ./cfg/nginx/django.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/django.conf
      - ./cfg/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/docker-entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      network: host
      context: src/.
    hostname: web
    expose:
      - "8000"
      - "22"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/web_reflectivity/app
      - web-static:/var/www/web_reflectivity/static
      - ./src/docker-entrypoint.sh:/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    env_file:
     - .env
    command: /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    restart: always
    image: code.ornl.gov:4567/rse/images/postgres:9.6.23
    env_file:
     - .env
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: code.ornl.gov:4567/rse/images/redis:6.2.5
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/log/web_reflectivity/redis:/var/log
      - ./cfg/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

  worker:
    image: code.ornl.gov:4567/rse/images/refl1d:0.8.15
    volumes:
      - ./cfg/worker/docker-entrypoint.sh:/opt/refl1d/docker-entrypoint.sh
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "22"
    command: /opt/refl1d/docker-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  pgdata:
  web-static:
```

Comment: you problaby run apache or something that spawns worker processes. It depends on the container you run. Please add more details like your compose file.

Comment: @TheFool I'm running `nginx` instead. I attached the compose file.

Comment: Well, nginx spawns worker processes. In general, the logs you see come from your containers.

Comment: then it looks like I have to figure out what is "worker process" in the context of `nginx`. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nginx` spawns processes to deal with incoming requests as they come.

[From the beginner's guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html):

> nginx has one master process and several worker processes. The main
> purpose of the master process is to read and evaluate configuration,
> and maintain worker processes. Worker processes do actual processing
> of requests. nginx employs event-based model and OS-dependent
> mechanisms to efficiently distribute requests among worker processes.
> The number of worker processes is defined in the configuration file
> and may be fixed for a given configuration or automatically adjusted
> to the number of available CPU cores